# python on linux trap end of program event

Tags: python, linux

How can I trap or be notified when a program reach the end, just before `exit`, so I can do some cleanup.

Capturing `try/except` errors and using signal from `import signal` allows me to capture most situations, however this is not enough, for example when using `deamonize`: the interactive task finish and start a new one in background, no control over the close.

To be more specific, when the 'pid' is released.

The module [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) is not a solution, as stated on the documentation:

> The functions registered via this module are not called when the
>   program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python
>   fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called

Comment: Write a separate program that launches the main program, then cleans up after it when it exits.

Comment: @kindall Actually this is the method I'm using, monitoring the process with `psutil`, but doesn't look as very 'elegant' solution and require two apps running.